# Aggregation/Joins in Order and Shipping tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL and I was facing a problem.
I have 2 tables as shown below,

Order_table

| Ord_num | Ord_date | Customer_name | Order_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2021-03-11 | ABC | 1000 |

Shipping_table

| Ord_num | Pkg_num | Pkg_weight | shipped_date | shipping_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | 30 | 2021-03-12 | 10 |
| 1111 | 2 | 20 | 2021-03-13 | 8 |

I wrote the following query,

```
select sum(order_total), sum(pkg_weight), sum(shipping_cost) 
from order_table O join shipping_table P 
on O.Ord_num = P.Ord_num
```

By this, if I sum my Order total, it shows 2000 but Order was only for 1000.

I basically want my output to be,

| Ord_num | Ord_date | Cust_name | Order_total | Pkg_num | shipped_date | pkg_weight | shipping_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2021-03-11 | ABC | 1000 | 1 | 2021-03-12 | 30 | 10 |
| 1111 | 2021-03-11 | ABC | 0 or null | 2 | 2021-03-13 | 20 | 8 |

The reason I want Order_total as 0 or null in the second line is because when I aggregate other columns like pkg_weight and shipping_cost, it should show their sum whereas for Order_total, it should not show as 2000 because the order was for 1000 but shipped in two different packages with 2 weights, 2 costs and shipped on 2 different days.

Can anyone help me what I should write my query as?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: " when I aggregate other columns like pkg_weight and shipping_cost" and where is this aggregation in your query?

Comment: I tried doing it and I haven't written that because I have many orders with being shipped on different days. So, when I want to find the sum as a whole, it will show double the amount for order total and correct amount for pkg_weight and shipping_cost.

Anyway, I will edit it right now. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

```
Declare @order_table Table (Ord_num int, Ord_date date, Customer_name varchar(30), Order_total int);
 Insert Into @order_table (Ord_num, Ord_date, Customer_name, Order_total)
 Values (1111, '2021-03-11', 'ABC', 1000)
      , (2222, '2021-04-11', 'XYZ', 2000);

Declare @shipping_table Table (Ord_Num int, Pkg_num int, Pkg_weight int, Shipped_date date, Shipping_cost int)
 Insert Into @shipping_table (Ord_Num, Pkg_num, Pkg_weight, Shipped_date, Shipping_cost)
 Values (1111, 1, 30, '2021-03-12', 10)
      , (1111, 2, 20, '2021-03-13', 8)
      , (2222, 1, 15, '2021-04-12', 5)
      , (2222, 2, 10, '2021-04-13', 3);

 Select ord.Ord_num
      , ord.Ord_date
      , ord.Customer_name
      , Order_total = iif(shp.Pkg_num = 1, ord.Order_total, 0)
      , shp.Pkg_num
      , shp.Shipped_date
      , shp.Pkg_weight
      , shp.Shipping_cost
   From @order_table                    ord
  Inner Join @shipping_table            shp On shp.Ord_Num = ord.Ord_num;
```

Which can then be converted to this for totals:

```
 Select ord.Ord_num
      , ord.Ord_date
      , ord.Customer_name
      , Order_total = sum(iif(shp.Pkg_num = 1, ord.Order_total, 0))
      , Pkg_weight = sum(shp.Pkg_num)
      , Shipping_cost = sum(shp.Shipping_cost)
   From @order_table                    ord
  Inner Join @shipping_table            shp On shp.Ord_Num = ord.Ord_num
  Group By
        ord.Ord_num
      , ord.Ord_date
      , ord.Customer_name;
```